# Update State of component from another component?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 component like code below

```
//component A    
const A = () => {
const [comA, setComA] = useState("1");
render()
}
export default A;

//component B
const B = () => {
render(<Button onclick={() => someThing }>

</Button>
)
}
export default B;
```

How can I update state `comA` in component `A` from `Button` in component B?

Comment: Is there a parent-child relationship between these two components?

Comment: Yes. Component B is child of Component A

Comment: In that case, just pass `setComA` as a prop to component `B` and from inside component `B`, call this function to update the state in component `A`.